# Comma-use and possibly other errors in text

Tags: grammar

Are their any error the text below?

> Other requirements:
>
> - Fluent English speaker
> - Excellent, near perfect grammar

Is the comma-use correct?

Comment: The *their* should be a *there*. And we don't do proofreading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is the comma-use correct?

Yes. *Near perfect* elaborates on the *excellent* required level of grammar.